Blazor drag/drop does not respect preventDefault and downloads file
Consider the following Blazor markup:
<div class="drag-drop-area @this.Conditional(isDragging, "drag-over")"

     @ondragenter="OnDragEnter"
     @ondragenter:preventDefault

     @ondragleave="OnDragLeave"
     @ondragleave:preventDefault

     @ondrop="OnDrop"
     @ondrop:preventDefault>

    <div class="h3 text-secondary">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-download"></i>
        <p>Drop a file here</p>
    </div>
</div>

private bool isDragging = false;

private void OnDragEnter(DragEventArgs e)
{
    isDragging = true;
    StateHasChanged();
}

private void OnDragLeave(DragEventArgs e)
{
    isDragging = false;
    StateHasChanged();
}


private void OnDrop(DragEventArgs e)
{
    isDragging = false;
    StateHasChanged();
}

The events are being respected because I can see the styles changing when the mouse enters or leaves the drag-drop-area, but preventDefault is not respected. Specifically, I want to drop CSV files into that region and access their data (that's the next challenge), but all this does is downloads the CSV file into my ~/user/Downloads directory.
Any ideas how to fix this?
Note: I am using C# 12, .NET 8, and Interactive Server rendering.

I think the syntax is @ondrop:preventDefault="true"

@GHDevOps I tried that too and it makes no difference. I read somewhere that omitting the ="true" is just shorthand.

I assumed. I'm using the drag/drop events via JSInterop and not pure Blazor.

You could try implement ondragover event and also set preventDefault to true like following:
<div class="drag-drop-areä"
     @ondrop="OnDrop"
     @ondrop:preventDefault="true"
     @ondragover="OnOver"
     @ondragover:preventDefault="true">

    <div class="h3 text-secondary">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-download"></i>
        <p>Drop a file here</p>
    </div>
</div>

@code{
    private bool isDragging = false;


    private void OnDrop(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var files = e.DataTransfer.Files;
        isDragging = false;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    private void OnOver(DragEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}

Test OnDrop is triggered to get file data


I solved it in the end, by implementing event handlers and preventDefault for all drag events.
